# Insert data only if record does not exist

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to insert data in a table only if the record with a given `CatalogID` does not exist.

```
 $userId = $_POST['userId'];
 $catalogID = $_POST['catalogID'];
 $content_AddedTime = $_POST['content_AddedTime'];

 $query = ("INSERT INTO LibraryMaster (UserID,CatalogID,ContentAddedDateTime)
      VALUES ('$userId','$catalogID','$content_AddedTime')");
 mysql_query($query,$con);
 printf("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
 echo($user_Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `UNIQUE` index on `CatalogID`.

Comment: in table structuer i may create but i want that if this is already then it should return me YES. also so

Comment: Then check for failure of the `INSERT` query.

Comment: how to check this can you please help me out in this

Comment: +1, hits the database once, you can check for errors via [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) I would recommend using PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="INSERT INTO LibraryMaster (UserID,CatalogID,ContentAddedDateTime)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$userId."', '".$catalogID."', '".$content_AddedTime."') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT CatalogID FROM LibraryMaster WHERE CatalogID = '".$catalogID."t'
 ) LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this sort of function

```
public function Checkrecord($catalogID )
    {
        $query="Select * from table_name where catalog_id=$catalogID ";
                  mysql_query($query,$con);
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
        {
            //report error
        }
        else
        {
            //insertQuery
        }
    }
```